# the grid does not appear in Share Column Configuration

Tags: acumatica

What code do we need to enter to make the grid appear in the share?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you have to be Administrator. When you change the column configuration by adding/hiding a column in the [Column Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8S8V.png)) of a grid and save it; then, the modified table will appear as an option when you click [share the column configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgXgD.png) option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer  the grid update will active function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).